# Azure Storage API - How authorization with shared key is working?

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I want to test the API of Azure Storage Service with Postman. For that I need a Shared Key which I have to encode before. 
My problem is,  when I try a GET-Request I get an error message 
I did the steps in the official microsoft documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/rest/api/storageservices/authorize-with-shared-key#constructing-the-canonicalized-headers-string

This is my code of the encoding process:

```
   public static String account ="ACCOUNT NAME";

DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEEE , dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss O");
String date = formatter.format(ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC));

String stringToSign = "GET\n"
        + "\n" // content encoding
        + "\n" // content language
        + "\n" // content length
        + "\n" // content md5
        + "\n" // content type
        + date  +"\n" // date
        + "\n" // if modified since
        + "\n" // if match
        + "\n" // if none match
        + "\n" // if unmodified since
        + "\n" // range
        + "x-ms-date:" + date
        + "\nx-ms-version:2019-07-07\n"
        + "/" + account + "/"
        +"\ncomp:list"; // resources


public  DirectoryController() throws Exception {
    try {
          String auth = getAuthenticationString(stringToSign);
          System.out.println(auth + date);
    }catch (Exception ex) {
        throw new Exception();
    }
}


private static String getAuthenticationString(String stringToSign) throws Exception {
    Mac mac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");
    String key = "KEY";
    mac.init(new SecretKeySpec(Base64.decode(key), "HmacSHA256"));
    String authKey = new String(Base64.encode(mac.doFinal(stringToSign.getBytes("UTF-8"))));
    String auth = "SharedKey " + account + ":" + authKey;
    return auth;
}
```

GET Request; https://ACCOTUNAME.file.core.windows.net/?comp=list

Did I set something wrong in the encoding process. 
I found out the dateformat is not like microsoft expected. I get Fr. as the day of the week and microsoft wants Fri.. How I get this?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, we can close this thread. I solved the problem. It was the wrong date format. With Local.US and without date argument in front of //date it works.